# Unable to retrieve value of templatefield textbox in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to pull the value populated in a templatefield textbox embedded in a gridview. I've tried to do this a couple of different ways but keep getting error messages. I am able to pull the value from a templatefield dropdown control embedded in the same gridview.

Markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Renewal Date" >
     <ItemTemplate>
          <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="cexRenewalDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtRenewalDate" PopupPosition="TopRight"
              Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="btnimgCalendar" />
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtRenewalDate" runat="server" CssClass="RenewalDateTextBoxStyle" 
              onKeyPress="javascript: return false;" onPaste="javascript: return false;"/>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="btnimgCalendar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" CssClass="CalendarImageButtonStyle"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpOFActions" runat="server" CssClass="ActionDropDownStyle"/>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOFCommit" runat="server" Text="  Commit  " OnClick="lnkCommitOF_Click" CssClass="CommitLinkButtonStyle"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to complete this action?');"
            CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
Dim temp As String = CType(grdGeneratedOrderForms.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("txtRenewalDate"), TextBox)
```

This throws a 'System.Web.UI.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' error.

I also tried using this on someone's suggestion:

```
Dim temp As String = TryCast(grdGeneratedOrderForms.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("txtRenewalDate"), System.Web.UI.Control.TextBox)
```

This throws a Type 'System.Web.UI.Control.TextBox' not defined error.

However when I use the below to pull the value of my dropdown control I have no issues:

```
Dim Action As Integer = TryCast(grdGeneratedOrderForms.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("drpOFActions"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
```

Here are my namespace declarations:

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Aspose.Words
Imports Aspose.Words.Tables
Imports Ionic.Zip
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. I think you have a namespace conflict in your using statements

```
Dim temp As String = CType(grdGeneratedOrderForms.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("txtRenewalDate"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox).Text
```

Comment: Thanks Kiran. That also gives me the Type 'System.Web.UI.Control.TextBox' not defined error. I added my namespace declarations in the original post.

Comment: Can you debug the code and check what what is the value of grdGeneratedOrderForms.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("txtRenewalDate")?

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to do that? I've been trying to figure out how to view object values within the gridview while debugging but have had no luck. Sorry if this is beginner's stuff.

Comment: Put a break point to the line you want to break. When exceution stops during run time, select part of the code for example grdGeneratedOrderForms.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("txtRenewalDate"), right click -> Add watch.

Comment: I can't do that because intellisense is throwing the error referenced above on that line of code.

Comment: Is it Windows application or web? In the question it mentioned asp.net. Why are you importing the namespace System.Windows.Forms? Can you also import the System.Web.UI.WebControls? I have made a change in the answer can you please try that?